# Why does DeveloperToolkit for IBM API Connect throw error on Windows10

Tags: apiconnect

Trying  to install IBM Developer Toolkit for API Connect on my Windows PC. I am getting the following error.

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\OpenSSL-Win64\lib\libeay32.lib' [C:\Users\arindch.WIPRO\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\apiconnect\n
ode_modules\ursa\build\ursaNative.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\msbuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (E:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10586
gyp ERR! command "E:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "E:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\arindch.WIPRO\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\apiconnect\node_modules\ursa
gyp ERR! node -v v4.4.7
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Answer (score 1):

APIC seems to be sentimental . :-) if you do not follow these steps for uninstalling and installing as mentioned below.

1. Ensure you have the correct C++ libraries:If you try to install IBM APIC Developer toolkit without the relevant C++ libraries, you will get MSBUILD error for lack of VC++ Compiler. It also suggests you to 1) install the .NET Framework SDK &  install Microsoft Visual Studio.
   I tried with different Visual Studio Community Edition  versions including the latest (2015), but had to settle with VS Community edition 2013 with Update 4.

2.Uninstall previous APIC and clear cache by

```
npm rm apiconnect -g --cache-clear
```

This should clear the cache. But you might try it explicitly

```
npm cache clean
```

To ensure that the cache is clear, take a look in %APPDATA%\npm-cache, or if you’re using PowerShell, $env:APPDATA\npm-cache

3. Reinstall: Run the cmd prompt as a Administrator and type the following commands

   apic stop --all

   Assuming you are not using trusted certificate, enter the following command

   npm config -g set strict-ssl false

Now run the installer

```
npm install -g apiconnect
```

4. Verify the installation by typing `apic -v`

Answer (score 1):

Ensure you have [`windows-build-tools`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-build-tools) installed globally before installing `apic`.

If you're on Windows 7, be sure that [.NET Framework 4.5.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40773) is also installed.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I think your suggestion to install windows-build-tools is better than installing VS and Python separately

Comment: I think so. I have had a good bit of trouble compiling npm modules with the VS + Python manual installs in general.